# Having trouble with SQL stored function syntax

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb

I have this problem and I don't know what it means.  As far as I understand you make a procedure inside a database so how do I write a procedure that specifies the database if it is different than the database I created the procedure in?  I have asked and not received any clarification from my instructor about this.  Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

Using SQL again, write a procedure that allows a user to specify a database, table, column in the table, and the new name of the index.  This allows a user to add indexes without remembering the SQL syntax.

This is what I have so far come up with, but it doesn't seem to work.  Or at least maybe I am writing the wrong thing in my query

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addindex`(
    IN `db_name` VARCHAR(255),
    IN `tbl_name` VARCHAR(255),
    IN `col_name` VARCHAR(255),
    IN `idx_name` VARCHAR(255)
)

BEGIN

  CREATE INDEX idx_name ON db_name.tbl_name(col_name);

END
```

what I put in the query

```
addindex(nation, countries, AREA, index_area);
```

nation, countries, and area are the database, table, and column of a database I am using for testing this.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'addindex(nation, countries, AREA, index_area)' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables, Database and Column names are identifiers and can't be variables.

What you can do in the body is use [execute immediate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) like:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('CREATE INDEX ',
                         idxname, ' on ', dbname, '.', tblname,
                         '(', col_name, ')')
```

Note this hasn't done table quoting. [QUOTE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/quote/) could be used around each of these identifiers.

Also consider compound multi-column indexes are useful and that stored procedures can't be written with a variable number of arguments. Hence `quote(col_name)` when multiple columns are passed will make it look like a single column.